# For loop in pandas('transfer' solution from R to pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to perform for loop in pandas: for each row `i` I want to take column `x1` and perform the test(if else statements)

In R I will do like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10),x2 = rexp(10))

for(i in 1:length(df$x1)){
  if(df[i,'x1'] >0){
    print('+')
  } else{
    print('-')
  }

}
```

How can I do this in pandas data frame?

P.S I need to perfom a loop like this. But if you have better ideas, I will appreciate it

EDIT:

In case multiple comparison:

Thank you for the answer!
And maybe you can give me an advise, how can i do the iteration if i have multiple if/else statements? For example:

```
if x>0:
   if x%2 == 0:
        #do stuff 1
   else:
         #do other stuff 2

elif x<0:
    if x%2 == 0:
        #do stuff 3
   else:
         #do other stuff 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need new column use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
np.random.seed(54)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':np.random.randint(10, size=10)}) - 5
df['new'] = np.where(df['x1'] > 0, '+', '-')
print (df)
   x1 new
0   0   -
1  -3   -
2   2   +
3  -4   -
4  -5   -
5   3   +
6   2   +
7  -4   -
8   4   +
9   1   +
```

But if need loop (obviously avoid it, because slow) is possible use [`iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html) or `items()`:

```
for i, x in df['x1'].iteritems():
    if x > 0:
        print ('+')
    else:
        print ('-')
```

EDIT:

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['x1'] > 0, 'a', 
            np.where(df['x1'] & 2, 'b', 'c'))

print (df)
   x1 new
0   0   c
1  -3   c
2   2   a
3  -4   c
4  -5   b
5   3   a
6   2   a
7  -4   c
8   4   a
9   1   a
```

But if have many conditions (4 or more) use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with custom function:

```
def f(x):
    #x == 0
    y = 5
    if x>0:
       if x%2 == 0:
           y = 0
           #do stuff 1
       else:
           y = 1  
           #do other stuff 2

    elif x<0:
        if x%2 == 0:
            y = 2
            #do stuff 3
        else:
            y = 3
            #do other stuff 4
    return y

df['new'] = df['x1'].apply(f)
print (df)
   x1  new
0   0    5
1  -3    3
2   2    0
3  -4    2
4  -5    3
5   3    1
6   2    0
7  -4    2
8   4    0
9   1    1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
And maybe you can give me an advise, how can i do the iteration if i have multiple if/else statements? I edited the post

Comment: You can use multiple `np.where`, check edited answer.

Comment: 3-4 conditions. Can you show the example with multiple np.where?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to print out each index with the correct symbol:

```
print(df['x1'].map(lambda x: '+' if x > 0 else '-').to_string(index=False))
```

What the above code does is creates a new Series object, for which you use the `map` function to convert each symbol into a `+` if `i>0` and a `-` if `i<=0`. Then, the Series is converted to a string and printed out without indices.

But if you absolutely need to loop through each row, you can use the following code, which is what you have but condensed into 2 lines:

```
for i in df['x1']:
    print('+' if i > 0 else '-')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
And maybe you can give me an advise, how can i do the iteration if i have multiple if/else statements? I edited the post

Comment: You can just replace the `print` statement with more if statements. If you would like more if/else statements when using `map`, you would have to define a new function that returns a boolean value, but it's not too much work.